# How to use libraries correctly in Netbeans (Java)?

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans, libraries

This question is about how to handle libraries in Netbeans, when programming in Java.

I am having a Java project, let's call it ABC. One of its activities is to send an email message. Some of my other Java projects also send email messages, so I decided to create a separate Java project for sending messages. This project is called SendEmail. SendEmail uses external jar files (javax.mail.*). These are included by going to SendEmail's project Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR. Testing SendEmail works fine: when calling its method sendMail(title, contents) do I receive the email which is sent.

Project ABC uses SendEmail, so I have added this to ABC's library: project Properties -> Libraries -> Add Project. ABC compiles and runs fine until it reaches the point where it wants to send an email: it crashes.

```
private void informUser(){
//create message title
//create message contents
SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
email.sendMail(title, contents); // <- it crashes here
}
```

The error information states that it can't find the Authenticator class. This class is in the external jar file which is included in SendEmail's library.
I can only avoid this crash from happening by including the external jar files to ABC's library. This is what I did not expect to be necessary. ABC does not use these external jar files, only SendEmail does.

My question: am I doing something wrong? I assumed that ABC is not using these external jar's so they don't need to be in ABC's library.

Answer (score 0):

In your code don`t have the authenticator part. This code only can use gmail email, you can change smtp server options. My code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GmailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }


}
```

And do you need this class:

```
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {
    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For used this code:

```
class SendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("from email", "from email password");
                //subject, body, sender, to
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                sender.sendMail("your title",
                        "your content",
                        "from email",
                        "to email");
            } catch (Exception e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
```

and run

```
SendEmailTask sendEmailTask = new SendEmailTask();
sendEmailTask.execute();
```

**UPD1:**
Libs: 
1. javax.activation
2. javax.mail

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that this answers my question. I do have a program which can send emails, as I've explained in the question. My question relates to using this email sending program in another Netbeans project, and the library settings required in that other project.